# Domain error in arguments using invgauss.rvs() function

Tags: python, debugging, scipy, valueerror

I'm trying to generate random gaussian random variables as follows:

```
mu = 0
k=10
r = invgauss.rvs(mu, size=k)
```

however I keep getting the following error

```
ValueError: Domain error in arguments.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

mu has to be greater than 0, according to [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.invgauss.html)

Comment: Thank you for the help, I also have a followup question. In the documentation it states that the probability density is in the "standardized form" however I'm not familiar with this form but rather only familiar with the Gaussian density the way it's presented the once googling "normal distribution formula" in the search engine. I'm not sure how to use the arguments to generate the following instance for invgauss(): I want to create a Gaussian random variable with parameters mean = M and standard deviation = S (for constants M and S). Any help would be greatly appreciate!